# How to set the number of copies to print from javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I am trying to print a document using print method of javascript.
Now i want to set number of copies to print(by default it will print 1 copy).i want to set the number of copies to two(2 copies).

Is it possible to do it from js code.We can set by printer settings,but it will print for all the copies.I need it for specific document to print 2 copies.

My code is :

```
  $scope.printPDF = function (id) {       
    window.frames["doc1"].focus();
    window.frames["doc1"].print();
    window.frames["doc2"].focus();
    window.frames["doc2"].print();
    window.frames["doc3"].focus();
    window.frames["doc3"].print();

};
```

Now i want to print doc2("only doc2") as 2 copies.remaining should be default 1 copy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are no additional parameters for the `window.print()` method and definitely no parameter that allows you to specify the default number of copies.

The only workaround for this that I can think of would be to call the `print()` method twice on doc2. Obviously not the greatest user experience.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, one solution would be to call the print twice

```
window.frames["doc1"].focus();
window.frames["doc1"].print();
window.frames["doc1"].focus();
window.frames["doc1"].print();
```